# Weird definition in Silverman's elliptic curve book

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves

Silverman's book, 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', p$195$, $4$-th line,

> Definition. Let $Σ$ be a set on which $G_{\bar K/K}$ acts. We say that $Σ$ is unramified at $v$ if the action of $I_v$ on $Σ$ is trivial.

But this definition does not specify how the Galois group $G_{\bar K/K}$ acts on $Σ$. Indeed, $G_{\bar K/K}$ can acts on arbitrary set by trivial action, so every set can be considered as unramified at $v$.

So I believe in a kind of sense, we should fix(specify) how $G_{\bar K/K}$ acts on
$Σ$.

How can I do that ? How can I make the definition meaningful?（Or where am I misunderstood the meaning of this definition?)

Comment: I actually think you understand the definition. It says that a $G$-set(a set with a G action, something like a representation) is unramified if the action of $I$ is trivial. the main source of $G$-sets in this book is the (torsion)$\bar{K}$ points of an eliptic curve defined over $K$

Comment: The action of $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ on a set is given as an assumption. We don't care how it looks like, we just make a general definition. Is the definition 'Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function. Then $f$ is continuous if $\dots$' also meaningless because we didn't specify $f$??